# Trying to post details to a third party form

Tags: php, forms, redirect, curl

I am trying to automate form submission and struggling to work out why it simply isn't working as I believe I have replicated what the browser does using PHP & curl.

Unfortunately the browser always ends up redirecting to an empty form.

Any pointers would be gratefully received!

Thanks in advance

The web form can be found https://www.abelliogreateranglia.co.uk/contact-us/contact-forms/delay-repay

The form itself posts to https://www.abelliogreateranglia.co.uk/_webformhandler

I believe my code successfully captures the cookies and "_token" required for posting.

My Curl Request looks OK

```
POST /_webformhandler HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36
Host: www.abelliogreateranglia.co.uk
Referer: https://www.abelliogreateranglia.co.uk/contact-us/contact-forms/delay-repay
Cookie: coanda_session=eyJpdiI6IjZmdXpKV2pGMWVEVlZaeE9rOHFFeUxKVDVMUUpJWUdQUkZqTDd3bUcwZlE9IiwidmFsdWUiOiJ6TGFsYWg5Z2I5N3E3YkRvaGR2eFBMXC9iWUoxalhsOEtvdGtLTXpMdEszWThmV1Y5OXJGSkhsczRQdERLVERYYUZIeFlKZ0RBSG5oTjk3dWdRZjd6U0E9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjdmNDRmOTZkODFmNDEyYzA3YTAwMmZhZmQ5OTkzN2VjMGMyMDdmYmJkZmVmNjNjMmUzMzVhYzQyZDEyOWJjOTYifQ%3D%3D; X-Mapping-fjhppofk=49656D7E5E95FCEF85BAACF2976B580C
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: https://www.abelliogreateranglia.co.uk
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 2606
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------e09ebcd7f8fd
```

And the response is always

```
string(754) "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Mon, 22 Jun 2015 09:55:28 GMT
Location: https://www.abelliogreateranglia.co.uk/contact-us/contact-forms/delay-repay
Set-Cookie: coanda_session=eyJpdiI6InpFWmJ1Tk9yVkd6NmVUSW1qYXlxOVRRejNQS0dpY3dHd1J6bGJuSW9iRFU9IiwidmFsdWUiOiJTbUFSRDBIaEZ1V0RpQzFmUmJndDlrU0NaNG9NV2dMcGg0ajZPQStsSW1Ic1c4RXA4aEZiY2xRekVwMGZ5OEZZRHJFSWpOQ01udFl3QTl3TTA5UHJ3QT09IiwibWFjIjoiZmEyMTM0MGE4OWQ5NDViZDA5OWRkOGU1MmI1NTM1ZDRmMDRmYmZlZjAxNTNiNzcwZGY5NTIzNDMxNDlkMDEyZSJ9; expires=Mon, 22-Jun-2015 11:55:28 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
```

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
<?php

$debug = isset($_GET['debug']);

// options
$cookie_file_path   = "/tmp/cookies".rand().".txt";
$LOGINURL           = "https://www.abelliogreateranglia.co.uk/contact-us/contact-forms/delay-repay";
$POSTURL            = "https://www.abelliogreateranglia.co.uk/_webformhandler";
$agent              = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36";


// begin script
$ch = curl_init(); 

// extra headers
$headers[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
$headers[] = "Connection: keep-alive";

// curl options 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,  1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 

// set first URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $LOGINURL);

// execute session to get cookies and required form inputs
$content = curl_exec($ch); 

$input_fields = array();

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);

$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "input" );
if ($elements->length==0) { 
   // no results 
   echo "No dom input nodes";
} else {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $input_fields[ $element->getAttribute('name') ] = $element->getAttribute('value');
    }
}

$token = "";

$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "select" );
if ($elements->length==0) { 
   // no results 
   echo "No dom select nodes";
} else {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $input_fields[ $element->getAttribute('name') ] = $element->getAttribute('value');
    }
}

ksort( $input_fields,  SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE );

foreach( $input_fields as $key => $val ) {
    if ( $key == "_token" ) {
            $token = $val;
        }
}

// grab the inputs for the form
$fields = array();
$fields['_token']=$token;
$fields['form_id']="6";
$fields['page_id']="1134";
$fields['field_132'] = "Other";
$fields['field_133'] = "John";
$fields['field_134'] = "Doe";
$fields['field_135'] = "";
$fields['field_136'] = "";
$fields['field_137'] = "30 mins+";
$fields['field_138'] = "";
$fields['field_139'] = "";
$fields['field_140'] = "";
$fields['field_257'] = "";
$fields['field_143'] = "";
$fields['field_144[hour]'] = "0";
$fields['field_144[minute]'] = "0";
$fields['field_147'] = "";
$fields['field_259'] = "";
$fields['field_260'] = "";
$fields['field_150'] = "Standard Class";
$fields['field_258'] = "";
$fields['field_149'] = "Annual Season Ticket";
$fields['field_152'] = "";
//$fields['field_153'] = "@";
$fields['submit_form'] = "";

// change URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $POSTURL); 

// set post options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 

//$headers[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate";
$headers[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8";
$headers[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
$headers[] = "Origin: https://www.abelliogreateranglia.co.uk";
$headers[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);

// perform post
$result = curl_exec($ch);  
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo "Curl Error<BR><pre>";
    var_dump( curl_error($ch));
    echo "</pre><BR><BR>";
}

if ( $debug ) {
    echo "Curl POST Header is<BR><pre>";
    var_export(curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT));
    echo "</pre><BR><BR>";
}

$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($result, $header_size);

if ( $debug ) {
    echo "Curl RESPONSE Header is<BR><pre>";
    var_dump( $header );
    echo "</pre><BR><BR>";
}
/* */
if ( $debug ) {
    echo "Curl RESPONSE body is<BR><pre>";
}
print_r( $body );
if ( $debug ) {
    echo "</pre><BR><BR>";
}
/* */


?>
```

Comment: Alas I am still struggling with this.

Comment: In a browser I have changed the posted to webpage to one of mine and have confirmed all the fields that are being passed and have positively checked them off against the ones I am posting.
I am thinking it might be to do with the final redirect and somehow the post variables are not been passed through properly but am struggling to prove or disprove that.